# equidistant points between two points in subarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have following matrix which represents xy points:

[image]

First column is **x** coordinate, second column is **y** coordinate, third is control column (with value 1 being control value). I need to create column with new values connecting directly points with value 1 in control column with interpolated points in between. New column need to be with same length.

I tried with `np.linspace` for each substring between `1` but I need it to be in one go without looping array.
Data can be downloaded from [this link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj5DfuTWg1OMl495JnRnLZp4P4AQfw?e=m5iHQV)

Comment: (1) With this little data you might as well just paste the matrix into the post. Don't show images of data and don't share links to data if it isn't necessary. (2) So you want to get all the data where the third column is 1 and get evenly-spaced (using x?) interpolated data?

Comment: is spacing between ones in the third column the same?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please add your desired results to your example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `np.interp`:

```
# random data
np.random.seed(1)
x = np.random.rand(20) * 10
y = np.random.rand(20) * 10
z = np.random.choice([0,1], size=20)

m = np.array([x,y,z]).transpose()
# ensure z starts and ends with 1
m[[0,-1],-1] = 1

# non-zero rows
xp = np.where(m[:,-1])[0]
# all the rows
x = np.arange(len(m))

# interpolate
out = np.array([np.interp(x, xp, fp=m[xp,0]),
                np.interp(x, xp, fp=m[xp,1]),
              ]).T
```

Output:

```
array([[4.17022005, 8.00744569],
       [3.78792194, 7.64603918],
       [3.40562383, 7.28463267],
       [3.02332573, 6.92322616],
       [1.46755891, 8.76389152],
       [1.66508051, 4.80716682],
       [1.86260211, 0.85044211],
       [3.45560727, 0.39054783],
       [4.42188731, 4.58598643],
       [5.38816734, 8.78142503],
       [4.27361906, 9.04724846],
       [3.15907078, 9.31307188],
       [2.0445225 , 9.5788953 ],
       [8.78117436, 5.33165285],
       [0.27387593, 6.91877114],
       [2.22346198, 6.89189021],
       [4.17304802, 6.86500928],
       [5.58689828, 8.34625672],
       [3.78395659, 7.92384993],
       [1.98101489, 7.50144315]])
```

You can visualize the data like this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.scatter(m[:,0], m[:,1], marker='x',s=100, label='old')
plt.plot(m[xp,0], m[xp,1], '--', label='none zero')
plt.scatter(out[:,0], out[:,1], marker='o', label='interpolate')
plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image]